# Duplicate menu items in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, osx, menus

As you can see in the screen shot below:

[image]

`Subdir` appears twice under `Subdir`. All the submenu items are identical

It also happens to `Operate`, `Mark`, `Regexp` and `Immediate` too

Here are the screenshot of the status lines:

*First frame*

[image]

*Second frame*

[image]

Not sure if these modes triggered this behaviour or  not

How can I remove this behavior?

Comment: The submenu content are identical.

Comment: You will probably need to bisect your init file to find the code that is adding the menu a second time. Or perhaps add more info to your question, so someone can guess what might be doing that.